# "network DISABLED" on new installation on Toshiba Satellite laptop

Tags: 18.04, wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on my Toshiba Satellite Intel Centrino laptop. It puts my WiFi into "airplane mode" but when I run `lshw` it shows:

```
*-network DISABLED
```

How do I enable this?

Comment: You need to provide the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`. Please add it to the question.

Comment: So it turns out I forgot the basic troubleshooting steps. My wifi was physically turned off at the switch on the laptop. I turned it on and everything worked out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [usb wifi is blocked by the hardware wifi switch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332856/usb-wifi-is-blocked-by-the-hardware-wifi-switch)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this myself. Unfortunately I forgot basic troubleshooting steps and forgot to physically turn on the wifi switch on the front of the laptop. Once I turned this on the problem was fixed.